# After updating windows 10 bootstrap css is not loading

Tags: css

today I got one windows 10 update , I just updated and after restarting system bootstrap css is not loading on my localhost and as well as on my live website. Previously I gave css path like this.

```
//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

Even I restarted system 3 times, still same issue. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Hope this help `https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: Yes, but before system update everything works like expected even with //netdna...

Comment: are you getting any console error? if it is unable to load the .css source file, it will give console error. @user3408779

Comment: i dont think so windows update will create bootstrap problem, what is the console error you are getting

Comment: Are you testing on IE or Edge?

Comment: No, on chrome and Mozilla